# on index page login not work but in inside project any page login work perfectly **After facebook login manual login not work.**

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I have used login for ajax.
I don't know what the issue is. In the index main page login does not work, but inside the project it works perfectly.

**After facebook login  manual login not work.**

I have tried in `Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password],true)` in if condition and check into auth user data via `dd(Auth::user());` but did not get any auth user data and when I tried with `print_r(Auth::user());` I got auth user data.

So I don't know what exactly the issue is. So please help me. Anyone know what is issue?

This is our login code

```
{{Form::open(array())}}
                            {{ Form::text('email','',array('class'=>'form-control __input-form mar-t-20','placeholder' => trans('common.email'),'id'=>'login_email'))}}
                            {{ Form::password('password',array('class'=>'form-control __input-form mar-t-20','placeholder' => trans('common.password'),'id'=>'login_password'))}}
                            <p class="text-left mar-t-10">
                                <a href="{{URL::to('/forgot-password')}}" class="text-grey">{{trans('common.forgot_password')}}</a>
                            </p> 
                            {{ Form::button(trans('common.login'),array('class'=>'form-control __input-form btn-main  mar-t-20','id'=>'login-btn'))}}
                        {{Form::close()}}

this is our login data send script

    //login user
    $('#login-btn').click(function(){

        var email = $('#login_email').val();
        var password = $('#login_password').val();
        var errorMessage = $('#loginErrorMessage');

        var data = {
            'email' : email,
            'password' : password
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: basePath + "/login",
            data : data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                var errors = '';  
                if(data.status)
                {
                    errors += "<p>"+ data.value +"</p>";
                    window.location.reload();
                }
                else
                {
                    $.each(data.value,function(index,item){
                        errors += "<p style='color:red;'>" + item + "</p>";
                    });
                }
                errorMessage.html(errors);
            }
         });

    });

this our controller code

    if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email,'password' => $request->password],true))
   { 

   return response()->json(['value' => 'Logged In Sucessfully.!!','status' => True]);

 }
```

Comment: Can you please show your ajax code and controller code?

Comment: can you help me @SmitRaval

Comment: I have added an answer please check.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use this code.

```
if(Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->input('email'),'password' => $request->input('password')],true))
   { 

   return response()->json(['value' => 'Logged In Sucessfully.!!','status' => True]);

 }
```

You are missing `$request->input();`

Check if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please parse JSON response and then check the status and do operation accordingly.

JAVASCRIPT CODE CHANGES :

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
   if(obj.status)
   {
    // do what you want to do if true
   }
   else
  {
    // do what you want to do if false
  }
```